# Visual Studio 2012 TFS Silent Check In issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, checkin

I appear to be having a sporadic issue with checking in code to my TFS 2010 server via Visual Studio 2012. Every few check-ins or so Visual Studio will not display the yellow bar above the "Team Explorer - Pending Changes" pane confirming the check-in with a change-set number. I will not receive the associated email as well. Sometimes the check-in will not occur at all with no message anywhere, nor the change-set incrementation in the Team Web Access website. Mind that I do frequently have **successful** check-ins.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a hanging "TFS Power Tool Shell Extension" (TfsComProviderSvr.exe). I notice this extension does not close when I close Visual Studio.

Comment: You mean hanging from a previous instance of Visual Studio? Or the current instance I'm trying to check in from?